# как анимировать изменение высоты у блока (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

с помощью ajax в один блок выводится разное количество информации, и этот блок изменяет свой размер под информацию соответственно, как анимировать это изменение высоты ? 
P.S Есть идея что нужно получать с помощью heigh() текущее значение высоты и использовать animate , но как подставлять возвращенное значение высоты в animate  я не знаю, ибо яваскрипт не изучал, (в дальнейшем планирую обязательно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не всё так просто, как может показаться на первый взгляд. [Набросал вам примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/AC8DA/). Обратите внимание, что на основной блок установлено css-правило **overflow: hidden;**, а динамическое добавление контента, происходит, так сказать, во вспомогательный внутренний блок-обёртку. А в целом, я надеюсь, что разберетесь.